# How to show waiting or progress bar using struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, progress-bar

How to show a progress bar or waiting page using jsp, struts2?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Execute and Wait Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html) is what you are looking for,The `ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor` is great for running long-lived actions in the background while showing the user a nice progress meter. This also prevents the HTTP request from timing out when the action takes more than 5 or 10 minutes.

have a look at the following [code](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsPleaseWait),Author has explained it in a very good way with a detailed example, hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and css to display div with "waiting message".